# How to use variables with forward slash in kubernetes chart?

Tags: charts, kubernetes

I defined the following parameters in values.yaml

```
resources:
  nvidia.com/gpu: 1
```

and in templates, I'd like to add following logic in `templates/deployment.yaml`

```
{{- if .Values.resources.nvidia.com/gpu }}
 ****
{{- end}}
```

But it's failed, please help me to know how to use it in `templates/deployment.yaml`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always use the function index:

```
  {{- if index .Values.resources "nvidia.com/gpu" }}
    x: {{ index .Values.resources "nvidia.com/gpu" }}
  {{- end}}
```